# Set Object to Array using Parse Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

Day, guys. I need to set append new object to **Array**, which placed in ***Parse.com***. Something like this:

```
    var myArray:NSArray = []
    myArray.append("newObject")
    PFObject.setObject(myArray, forKey: "ArrayParse")
```

My goal - is saved Username to Array and get them, from array in parse. Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use a fonction like this :

```
func saveUsernameToParse(){
    var usernames = ["Jon", "Joe", "Jim"]
    var parseClass = PFObject(className: "_User")

    for username in usernames {
        parseClass["username"] = username
        parseClass.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if success == false {
                println(error)
            } else {
                println("Posted succesfully")
            }
        }
    }
}
```